# Can't build hidapi rust example

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, hidapi

```
filip@filip-pc:~/Desktop/hidTest$ cargo build
   Compiling pkg-config v0.3.17
   Compiling libc v0.2.71
   Compiling cc v1.0.54
   Compiling hidapi v1.2.2
error: failed to run custom build command for `hidapi v1.2.2`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/filip/Desktop/hidTest/target/debug/build/hidapi-f1cb7b18f844a4a0/build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stderr
thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to find libusb-1.0: "`\"pkg-config\" \"--libs\" \"--cflags\" \"libusb-1.0\"` did not exit successfully: exit code: 1\n--- stderr\nPackage libusb-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `libusb-1.0.pc\'\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\nNo package \'libusb-1.0\' found\n"', /home/filip/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/hidapi-1.2.2/build.rs:65:21
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I just try to run the example from docs https://docs.rs/hidapi/1.2.2/hidapi/

Have anybody encounter this error ?

I already try

> cargo clean

and

> cargo build

again

Comment: *Unable to find libusb-1.0* — install it.

Comment: Or more probably, install libusb-dev

Comment: no, it doesn't work

Comment: Actually, *uninstalling* libusb-dev (and libusb-0.1-4 or similar) may be required.  I had this issue when both those and libusb-1.0-0 (and libusb-1.0-0dev) were installed, and removing the older one allowed the build to complete without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install libusb-1.0 on your system. You seem to be using Homebrew, so you also have to install it specifically via Homebrew, because that's where pkg-config is looking for it.

It's possible that Homebrew doesn't offer this library under this exact name, or that the `hidapi` crate isn't compatible with macOS. Check the `hidapi` crate for details, as it's a crate-specific problem.

Comment: I use ubuntu and I should go to https://github.com/libusb/libusb/releases to download and install. Thanks